# \int command skipped in compilation

Tags: errors, symbols, compiling

If I am writing like this: `\int_a^b` or `\int_{a}^{b}` it skip the `\int` and writing  only `a to the power b` but when I am writing only `\int` without limits it is showing the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\protect
\{->\x@protect \{\protect
\{
\int #1->\csname i-#1
\endcsname
l.56 (u_1,u_2) = -i \int \{
u_1(x) \partial_0 u_2^*(x) - u_2^*(x)\partial_0 ...
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Extra \endcsname.
\int #1->\csname i-#1\endcsname
l.56 (u_1,u_2) = -i \int \{
u_1(x) \partial_0 u_2^*(x) - u_2^*(x)\partial_0 ...
```

The equation is like this:

```
\begin{equation} 
(u_1,u_2) = -i \int \{ u_1(x) \partial_0 u_2^*(x) - u_2^*(x)\partial_0 u_1(x)\} [\sqrt{-g_{\Sigma}(x)}] \mathrm{d}\Sigma 
\label{Inner Prod}
\end{equation}
```

When I am writing like

```
\begin{equation} 
(u_1,u_2) = -i \int\limits_{u}^{e} \{ u_1(x) \partial_0 u_2^*(x) - u_2^*(x)\partial_0 u_1(x)\} [\sqrt{-g_{\Sigma}(x)}] \mathrm{d}\Sigma 
\label{Inner Prod}
\end{equation}
```

it is showing the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\limits
\int #1->\csname i-#1
\endcsname
l.56 (u_1,u_2) = -i \int\limits
_{u}^{e} \{ u_1(x) \partial_0 u_2^*(x) - u_2^...
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.
<recently read> \limits
\int #1->\csname i-#1
\endcsname
l.56 (u_1,u_2) = -i \int\limits
_{u}^{e} \{ u_1(x) \partial_0 u_2^*(x) - u_2^...
I'm ignoring this misplaced \limits or \nolimits command.
! Extra \endcsname.
\int #1->\csname i-#1\endcsname
l.56 (u_1,u_2) = -i \int\limits
_{u}^{e} \{ u_1(x) \partial_0 u_2^*(x) - u_2^...
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
```

It is clear that it is skipping but I am not able to read the error. What is csname? What is protected in first error?

I used TexMaker with MikTex.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Please, make complete but minimal document, which exhibit your error and can be compiled.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the error, based on the code snippet you've posted so far. Please provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the error.

Comment: Is it not possible to read the error and tell what's defined wrong. Otherwise I can put my content in some other template. It will be a lot of work that's why I am asking this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the question remains" fontinst should never be used in a _document_ (it is a font building program written in tex) using it in a document is quite likely to break something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error was caused by an issue which was not revealed in the posting itself and was only reported in a subsequent comment posted as as answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error log shows

```
 \int #1->\csname i-#1
```

some code that you have not shown has defined `\int` by something equivalent to

```
\renewcommand\int[1]{\csname i-#1}
```

so it no longer denotes an integral sign, and you get the errors that you state.

Comment: I tried this but this is also not working:
`\let\oldint\int
\renewcommand{\intg}[1]{\oldint}`
 How to define something like \intg for integral sign? Or is there any other definition exists for integral sign?

Comment: @LoveGrover You could just do `\let\oldint\int` and then use `\oldint` as long as you do the `\let` before the code that mangles `\int`. But that is just paper over the cracks, the real fix is not to redefine `\int` but you have not shown why that is happening.

Comment: The problem was with \usepackage{fontinst} I don't remember why I used this package. But commenting this line solved the problem. Thanks for your help! :)